# XAMPP via SSH: Accessing localhost on a remote machine

Tags: networking, server, ssh, xampp

I have a network with multiple computers (wireless, if that matters), and I am trying to set up XAMPP on one of the computers and access it on another one (both are using Ubuntu 16.04). I have XAMPP installed on the one I'd like to use as a server, and then I access it through SSH with X11 server clearance/permission:

```
ssh -X User@MyComputer
```

I then open a firefox window and enter the address http://localhost, and firefox says there's a problem loading page, unable to connect. I also notice that the firefox window that I have open remotely mimics the settings and browsing history of my local computer. Why is the remote instance of the browser mimicking my local instance? More importantly, how can I access the localhost page of my remote computer via SSH, if it's possible?

Comment: Got it, entered MyComputer instead and got to a Access Forbidden page. I believe I can use the following for further guidance:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083323/error-when-trying-to-access-xampp-from-a-network

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`localhost`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) means the same computer by definition. The correct way to address another computer is to use its network name like `MyComputer` or its IP address. So you should use `http://MyComputer`.

SSH is not related to HTTP connection, they are different [application protocols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer). (There is a possibility to [tunnel HTTP over SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/78351/can-i-create-ssh-to-tunnel-http-through-server-like-it-was-proxy) but it is absolutely not necessary for a [local network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_area_network).)